# Having a "book-keeping" kind of class over the class that does the actual implementation

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Consider the following class:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    CheckIfAIsPositive();  // validates value of a
}
```

Say I want another class as a kind of an interface/wrapper over this class, i.e. the outside world would interact through that class only.

The interface class would have generic function names (e.g `Validate ()`), that would internally call functions of `A`. (e.g `Validate()` function of the wrapper class would call `CheckIfAIsPositive()` function of `A`.

This call to `CheckIfAIsPositive()` would be made after some error checking of `public` variables of `A`).

What design pattern could implement this thinking?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want some kind of an Adapter? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: That's way too general to be any kind of design pattern.  Basically, what your describing is an abstraction.  A class hides the details of another class and provides a slightly different interface.  It could fit any number of design patterns.  It would depend on more details of your use case.

Comment: @Pace, will look into the adapter pattern and come back with more details if it doesn't cut it.